# The ')' character, hexadecimal value 0x29, cannot be included in a name

Tags: xml, sharepoint, calculated-field

I am facing an issue by programmatically setting a formula for a sharepoint calculated field, here is the xml that I generate:

```
<Field ID='3bc3a7ac-a5bc-49e0-b430-a987ddac42f7' Type='Calculated' Name='Comparison' StaticName='Comparison' DisplayName='Comparison' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>
  <Formula>=IF(AND(CampoA>CampoB,CampoA<CampoC),&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Not OK&quot;)</Formula>
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoC'/>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoB'/>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoA'/>
  </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

And it gives me the error: The ')' character, hexadecimal value 0x29, cannot be included in a name. Do I have to escape parenthesis?

Comment: You need to escape the < with `&lt;`

Comment: And `>` with `&gt;`

Comment: Escaping the > is not absolutely necessary, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I have escaped both > and < and now it gives me the error {"An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 186."}

Comment: Very true, but how is it generated? Because for example [tag:php] has the `html_entities()` function and in python for example you have the `str.escape()` method.

Comment: here is the new xml: <Field ID='4cb963a4-35c8-4dd7-aa64-0c6e44a28e5f' Type='Calculated' Name='Comparison' StaticName='Comparison' DisplayName='Comparison' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>&ltFormula&gt=IF(AND(CampoA&gtCampoB,CampoA&ltCampoC),&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Not OK&quot;)&lt/Formula&gt<FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoC'/>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoB'/>
    <FieldRef Name='CampoA'/>
   </FieldRefs>
  </Field> I use Csom code

Comment: @OuterSpace You are escaping xml elements: "`&lt/Formula&gt`", something you dont want to do. Only do it on the values.

Comment: I got but its a joint string I cannot separate the value, instead isn't there something wrong with parenthesis? I had another formula with > and < and it worked without escaping

Comment: If you had `<` in your xml, it would have expected a new element and therefor it is crucial to escape it. I don't see how it would have worked in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `Formula` element, you need to escape the `<` with `&lt;`...

```
<Field ID='3bc3a7ac-a5bc-49e0-b430-a987ddac42f7' Type='Calculated' Name='Comparison' StaticName='Comparison' DisplayName='Comparison' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>
 <Formula>=IF(AND(CampoA>CampoB,CampoA&lt;CampoC),&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Not OK&quot;)</Formula>
 <FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef Name='CampoC'/>
  <FieldRef Name='CampoB'/>
  <FieldRef Name='CampoA'/>
 </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

If you had literal `&` characters you would also need to escape those with `&amp;`.

Another option is to wrap the content in CDATA...

```
<Field ID='3bc3a7ac-a5bc-49e0-b430-a987ddac42f7' Type='Calculated' Name='Comparison' StaticName='Comparison' DisplayName='Comparison' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'>
    <Formula><![CDATA[=IF(AND(CampoA>CampoB,CampoA<CampoC),&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Not OK&quot;)]]></Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef Name='CampoC'/>
        <FieldRef Name='CampoB'/>
        <FieldRef Name='CampoA'/>
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

I'm not sure if you'd want literal `&quot;` in your formula. If not, change those to `"` in the CDATA section.

Comment: <Field ID='9380e3a5-e7fa-447e-9241-82611c0c5b27' Type='Calculated' Name='Comparison' StaticName='Comparison' DisplayName='Comparison' ResultType='Text' Required='TRUE' ReadOnly='TRUE'><Formula>=IF(AND(CampoA&gtCampoB,CampoA&ltCampoC),&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Not OK&quot;)</Formula><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name='CampoC'/><FieldRef Name='CampoB'/><FieldRef Name='CampoA'/></FieldRefs></Field> I have escaped the content but it gives me an error at position 209 where there is the &gt

Comment: @OuterSpace - That's because you didn't properly close the entity reference with `;` (for gt and lt)

Comment: Flawless, to the point answer, couldn't have done it better myself. But I wounder, the first set of code is indexed with 1 space, the second is not. When I was editing I encountered the issue where code would disappear. Did you encounter that as well?

Comment: @OuterSpace Then upvote and mark it, it says thank you enough.

Comment: @Xorifelse - Thanks! I didn't notice the difference in code indenting. In the first set I just copied/pasted/modified from the question. In the second set I copied from oXygen where I double checked my work. As long as there are 4 spaces before the code, it _should_ work ok.